# Autodetect new content from mysql , then updating page without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a blog. How can i make it auto update its content whenever a new row is inserted trough a mysql table?

If needed, here is a piece of my code that would display the different posts within PHP.

```
$kake = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Poster` WHERE `published` = 'yes' ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($info = mysql_fetch_object($kake)){
    $id = $info->id;
    ?>
<div class="entry">
<br>

<h2>
<a href="<? echo $adresse;?>?side=read&les=<?echo $id;?>"><? echo $info->tittel;?></a>
</h2>
<div class="meta">
<ul>
<br><br>
<div id="dato">
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content"><p style="text-align: center;"><? echo $info->beskrivelse;?><br><center>
<a href="<? echo $adresse;?>?side=read&les=<?echo $id;?>">Les hele innlegget...</a></center>

</div>
<div class="meta">
<ul>
<div id="dato2">
<? echo $info->dato;?> <li> 15:11<li>
Postet i: <a href="<? echo $adresse;?>/blogg.html"><? echo $info->tema;?></a>
<li>
<a href="http:/t_bloggen.html#comment"><? 

$kakeer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `kommentarer` WHERE `innleggid` = '$id' ORDER BY id ASC");
$kommentarer = mysql_num_rows($kakeer);

echo $kommentarer;?> kommentarer</a>
</li>
</ul>
<br><br>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<? }
} ?>
```

and are getting the details from my mysql database. so for newest content i have to refresh. how can i do so i dont need to refresh?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to do some research first

Comment: If you show us code with a reasonable task we'll help solve it. We won't build your blog for you.

Comment: added a piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is indeed called AJAX. Have a look at [AJAX Tutor](http://www.ajax-tutor.com/index.html). Basically you have to put all your database code in a separate PHP script (Server side), which only outputs text or JSON, open an XMLHttpRequest and update your content using Javascript (Client side).

To automatically update an open browser window you can either periodically check for updates using AJAX, or use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).